# Develop application in Angular, Node.js, NestJS and Firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, architecture, nestjs

I have an application developed in [Angular](https://angular.io/), [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

At the moment all the logic and business rule of my application in Angular is within the services that Angular provides, so I need to perform dependency injection in my components for the consumption of the data of the [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).

My company is expanding with other applications that are also in healthcare, and I need to create a backend to handle every business rule of my application in a separate way from my Angular project.

I recently met [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/), and I would love to use it as the backend of my application developed with Angular.

My question is whether you can restructure my application in Angular, Node.js, and the persistence of Cloud Firestore and [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) offline data by creating a backend with Nestjs so that you can continue to use the benefit of working with my application on offline mode.

---

**A summary of what I need:**

**1.** Create a backend with Nestjs where my entire business rule will stay.

**2.** Consume the backend written in Nestjs in my Angular application so that you can insert, update, and delete data from my database in Cloud Firestore.

**3.** Reuse modules in other applications Angular or other front-end development frameworks.

**4.** In my Angular application, I do not want to make HTTP requests to consume the data from my backend, since I want to use the benefits of Cloud Firestore persistence of offline data.

I realized that there is the [Cloud Firestore API RPC](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc), could I work with [NestJS gRPC](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/grpc)? Reminding me that I would like to keep data persistence offline in my Angular application.

Is it possible to have a well-written system with Angular, Node.js, NestJs and the features that Firebase offers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question, you want `localstorage` functionality in the app, you want structure of the app like

- frontend is always getting data from localstorage
- whenever app gets access to network, it refreshes its localstorage with cloud firestore behind the scenes so that app will never get slow

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score -1):

No support for this use case yet.

Learn more about current limitations here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDvdAFP6OhQ&t=527s